# How can i hide/show the quick launch based on users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, quick-launch

I know how to hide the quicklaunch.

My scenario is this:

I have built a custom quicklaunch that I show to all users but I only won't some contributors to see the default quicklaunch so that they can actually add content to lists and libraries.
Is there a way I can wrap some security trimming around the default default quicklaunch.
Also I read that I can use Target Audience but my site is not a publishing site but a Team site.
Any resources or tips ill be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a slightly more complicated approach to this. I needed to hide and display quick launch links on the user profile page based on the user's relationship to the viewer. I did this by:

1. Used jQuery to hide the link / links
2. Used jQuery to call a web service and see if the logged in user was the manager of or in an admin group to see if they could view the profile.
3. Used jQuery to show the links if the second step was true.

Comment: Thanks RWL01.
I used Jquery and SPServices>
I would try and blog about it if i find time.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following in your master page to only show the default quicklaunch to Contributors (Users who can add list items)

```
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="AddListItems">
            <SharePoint:AspMenu
                  id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
                  runat="server"
                  EnableViewState="false"
                  DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
                  UseSimpleRendering="true"
                  UseSeparateCss="false"
                  Orientation="Vertical"
                  StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                  MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
                  SkipLinkText=""
                  CssClass="s4-ql" />
        </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before by doing the following:

1. Customize the masterpage to have the quicklaunch as a delegate control
2. Create an ascx file that has the quicklaunch controls in it from the masterpage.
3. Include some inline code to show the default quicklaunch controls or your own.
4. Modify your web.config to allow inline code in your ascx file

   PageParserPath VirtualPath="/_controltemplates/Custom/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true"

With this setup you can have a feature that turns on your customization for any site that you need it.